# Send request to server from PDF file when the PDF is opened in a browser

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am working on a POC where I need to show impact of opening an untrusted PDF file. I just need to demonstrate the security issue on opening the PDF file.

I only need to send request to a server. User will be downloading the PDF file from the email. I used Adobe JavaScript API

```
app.launchURL("http://localhost", true);
```

It is working on Adobe Acrobat but not when opening with a browser. How do use that API or open a connection if the PDF is opened in a browser?

Comment: Many browser based PDF viewers do not support Javascript inside PDF for that very reason

Comment: there needs to be a mechanism that is supportable by both Acrobat and Browser